# Jquery: Setting/removing two attributes at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am upcoming learner with jquery. Does anyone know how to give set two attributes at once that fit into the below example?

**For the moment I am only able to give it one attribute. My goal is to able to give two attributes to a select box  'disabled' and 'hidden'**

```
obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
```

**Same things goes for removing the attributes: 'disabled' and 'hidden'**

```
obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
obj.nextAll('.update')
 .attr({
    disabled: true,
    hidden: true
 })
 .html('<option value="">----</option>');
```

According to @nnnnnn comment `.prop()` might be more appropriate than `.attr()`

i.e

```
obj.nextAll('.update')
 .prop({
    disabled: true,
    hidden: true
 })
 .html('<option value="">----</option>');
```

**[DEMO for adding multiple attr](http://jsfiddle.net/yU89X/1/)**

To remove

```
// from jQuery1.7, it can be a space-separated list of attributes.

obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled hidden');
```

**[DEMO for remove multiple attr](http://jsfiddle.net/LxsFs/1/)**

Comment: is there such thing hidden attribute? Is it HTML5?

Comment: Note that [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) might be more appropriate than `.attr()` (assuming jQuery version >= 1.6). @Naor - Yes, html5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708247/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hidden-attribute-html5-and-the-displaynone

Comment: @thecodeparadox Hey my friend! once again Thank you. I have learned alot from you today and i appreciate the demos :). I was setting those values incorrectly and now i see why it wasn't working.

Comment: @thecodeparadox sorry I forgot check your answer. But yes the issues have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
obj.attr({ firstAttr:firstVal,  secondAttr:secondVal});
```