# How can I hide a checkbox in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide a `checkbox`.
But also want that, when I click on label associated with corresponding `checkbox`, the `checkbox` should get checked/unchecked.

I also want that the `checkbox` MUST be able to be focused.

I am doing the following:

```
<div class="menuitem">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="valueofcheckbox" style="display:none" checked="checked">Option Text</label>
</div>
```

The problem with above is, I am not able to make focus the `checkbox` when `style="display:none"`.

To make `checkbox` focusable I am doing :

```
$('input', '.menuitem').focus();
```

IF POSSIBLE, how do I make the hidden `checkbox` focusable?

Comment: Would adding a `tabindex` to the label work?

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions Erm... say that again, slowly? *REMOVES* it from the DOM? Really?

Comment: visibility:hidden also does not work.. i have tried it.

Comment: You want it "hidden" but you also want it to receive "focus" and get checked/unchecked?  What are you trying to accomplish with all this verbose contradiction?  Surely, there's a better way... try `<input type="hidden" />` to store/send whatever it is.

Comment: maybe use `<label for="check">some text</label><input type="checkbox" name="check" style="display: block;"/>` type 'name' attribute of checkbox in 'for' attribute of label

Comment: @Sparky : can u please let me know the better way, that fullfil my needs.

Comment: A better way to do what?  You never explained the purpose of all this?  (See last paragraph of Mike Christensen's answer).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try setting the checkbox's opacity to 0. If you want the checkbox to be out of flow try `position:absolute` and offset the checkbox by a large number.

**HTML**

```
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="valueofcheckbox" checked="checked" style="opacity:0; position:absolute; left:9999px;">Option Text</label>
```

Comment: This would be more like `visibility: hidden` than `display: none` though.

Comment: I updated your fiddle; the solution is sloppy, but focus and checking work. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unblevable/fwCkf/)

Comment: Not that visibility:hidden will take it's space.

Answer (score 14):

Elements that are not being rendered (be it through `visibility: hidden`, `display: none`, `opacity: 0.0`, whatever) will not indicate focus.  The browser will not draw a focus border around *nothing*.

If you want the *text* to be focusable, that's completely doable.  You can wrap the whole thing in an element that can receive focus (for example, a hyperlink), or allow another tag to have focus using the `tabindex` property:

```
<label tabindex="0" class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="valueofcheckbox" style="display:none" checked="checked" />Option Text
</label>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2ZbB/)

In this case, the `<label>` tag above is actually receiving focus and everything within it will have a focus border when it's in focus.

I do question what your goal is.  If you're using a hidden checkbox to internally track some sort of state, you might be better off using a `<input type="hidden" />` tag instead.

Comment: the hidden checkbox is still not focusable in my work... can u please edit n save the fiddle to actually show the hidden checkbox focusable?

Comment: You can't make a hidden element focusable.  No matter what.  The browser won't draw a focus ring around *nothing*.

Comment: if that is true, there is no need for tabindex.. the result would be same even without tabindex=0

Comment: You can add `label:focus{outline:1px solid black}` to your CSS.

Comment: @Koka, what are you really trying to accomplish here?  Your specifications are nothing but an exercise in contradiction.  Focus all of your attention and energy to this answer's very last paragraph.

Comment: @Koka - Adding `tabindex` makes the *label* tag focusable, not the hidden `<input>` tag.

Comment: i am trying to make my own dropdown using div and inside i have so many labels with input checkbox to find if checked or not.

Comment: i dont want user find a checkbox visible.. to get look and feel of normal dropdown. i also want when dropdown div opens the first item input checkbox (that is hidden) automatically get focused. (for sake of keyboard handling)

Comment: @Koka, if the user never sees the `checkbox` then I don't understand why you'd want to use a `checkbox`.  Do you know about `<input type="hidden" />` elements?

Comment: if i use type=hidden will there exist a checkbox??

Comment: btw checkbox is for internal (hidden) use TO FIND if the item is selected.

Comment: @Koka, of course not.  Why do you want to use a `checkbox`, when a `checkbox` is never seen?

Comment: check my above comment plz

Comment: @Koka - Yea, if it were me, I'd make the `<label>` tags focusable, and call `.focus()` on the *label*, not the *input*.  Or, maybe just make each option an `<a>` tag (which can receive focus by default) and trap the `click` event to toggle the checked state.

Comment: @Koka, if the `checkbox` is only for "internal" hidden use, then do yourself a huge favor and research the proper usage of `<input type="hidden" />`.

Comment: @Koka - Using a hidden checkbox is fine to *internally* track which options are checked or not.  However, you can't use that *same tag* for focus and tabbing.  You need to handle that aspect through another tag, such as `<label>` or `<a>`.

Comment: i also want it to be multiselect dropdown.. so i have to use checkbox.. i also use some css to display the selected items in case of multiselect dropdown.. but not showing the checkbox to end user.. Is there a way to achieve the same without loosing my checkbox..??

Comment: your answer and comments are fair enough make your answer acceptable. But just a kind of extra help, can u help me out from this problem?

Comment: @Koka - All this is perfectly fine.  Using a hidden `<input>` tag (be it a `checkbox` or `hidden` type) is a reasonable approach.  The thing you *can't* do is set the focus to a hidden element.  You need to set the focus to something else.

Answer (score 12):

This two classes are borrowed from the [HTML Boilerplate main.css](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css). Although the invisible checkbox will be focused and not the label.

```
/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screenreaders: h5bp.com/v
 */

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

/*
 * Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element to be focusable
 * when navigated to via the keyboard: h5bp.com/p
 */

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

### `input` may have a *[hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6708247/104380)* attribute:

```css
label{ cursor:pointer; user-select:none; }
input:checked + span::before {
  content: 'un';
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type='checkbox' hidden/>
  <span>check</span>
<label>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your check box to keep its height and width but only be invisible:

```
.hiddenCheckBox{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

if you want your check box to be invisible without any with and height:

```
.hiddenCheckBox{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Both ways the checkbox is not focusable, don't use this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the element type to the class, otherwise it will not work.

```css
.hide-checkbox { display: none }        /* This will not work! */
input.hide-checkbox { display: none }   /* But this will. */
```

```html
<input class="hide-checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
```

It looks too simple, but try it out!