# How to make a hidden checkbox in php?

Tags: php, html, css

I've got a set of checkboxes but one shuld be always checked, I want that this checkbox is also hidden from my page, I need this beacause I have the DB that can be read only if this attribute is checked..
Please I need answers where you teach me how to hide the checkbox and NOT where you say that I can change the comand on SQL

```
$sqlPers= "SELECT * FROM personalizzazione";
$countPers = 0;
foreach ($dbh->query($sqlPers) as $rowPers){
    $selez = '';
        if($rowPers['Condimento'] == 'Base')
            $selez = " checked = 'checked' ";
    echo "<div class='checkbox'><label class='bianco'><input type='checkbox'" . 
          $selez . "name='".$rowPizza["idPizze"]."_".$rowPers["idPersonalizzazione"].
          "' id='".$rowPizza["idPizze"]."_".$rowPers["idPersonalizzazione"]."'>".
          $rowPers['Condimento']."&nbsp;(&euro; &nbsp;".$rowPers['Prezzo'].")</label></div>";
          $countPers++;
}
```

I tried to add `type = 'hidden'` in the variable $selez but nothing

Otherwise can someone say me how to disable it or hide it throught ccs?
I've tried searching on internet and there weren't full solutions for my question

Comment: It can't be type hidden and checkbox. You can either disable it or use css to hide it.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Can you write me how to hide it in css or disable it?

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, but I've bookmarked and will check back later if no one else jumps on it

Comment: display :none or visibility:hidden

Comment: @NagaSaiA this time you are using css right? :D

Comment: yes http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqjWxJ

Comment: for instyle , we use style="display:none" and in CSS use display:none for that element id or class specific to that element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hide a checkbox in html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979781/how-can-i-hide-a-checkbox-in-html)

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not good in Javascript, that's why there are tags saying 'html, css, php'..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

**Method 1 - Hide it using CSS:**

```
<input type='checkbox' style='display:none;'>
```

**Method 2 - Use a hidden type instead of checkbox:**

Another option would not have a checkbox, but rather have a separate `hidden` input tag.

```
<input type='hidden' name='pizza' value='value'>
```

Comment: This is the best answer and I was going to write the same. You can then change the `display: none;` with JS.

Comment: This checkbox is generated form the DB, your answer makes only the checkbox hide, I need to hide also the description

Comment: @Biondo Easy! Just apply the `style='display:none;'` to the `<div class="checkbox">...</div>` rather than the `<input>`

Comment: @StephenCioffi you are saying that I should move the variable $selez in div and the game is done?  I'll try it tomorrow because It's 3:30 am in Italy  I need to sleep

Comment: @Biondo No, leave `$selez` where it is. That code is the part that is actually checking off the box. To hide the checkbox and description, simply change `<div class='checkbox'>` to `<div class='checkbox' style='display:none;'>`

Comment: @StephenCioffi but doing so it will hide all the checkboxes, I need to hide only one not all the set..
Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @StephenCioffi I solved using a new variable setted after an if were i gave the 'display:none' if it was in true and '&nbsp;' if it was wrong.. I know that is not right doing so much mess but it is the only way I could without touching all the rest of my code ;)

Answer (score -1):

Look at the HTML that gets sent to the browser: You have already set `type='checkbox'` in your string, so having an additional `type='hidden'` may not give you what you want.  You end up with `<input type='checkbox' type='hidden'...`

Your error was tough to see because you're writing your code in a way that is really difficult to debug.  It's better practice to do all the logic up front. You're better off building all the attributes in code first.  For example:

```
//run test to make $hide true for the loop where you want to hide the checkbox
$type = 'checkbox';
$style = $hide? "display:none" : "";
$name = $id = "$rowPizza[idPizze]_$rowPers[idPersonalizzazione]";
...

//then later when you can build your html

$html = "<div class='checkbox'><label class='bianco'><input type='$type' name='$name' id='$id' style='$style'>";

//Finally once you've built the whole html you can echo it
echo $html;
```

Note that we set `display:none` style when the `$hide` variable is true.  Otherwise, the style will just be an empty string and the checkbox will be shown

Comment: You are absolutely right but the checkbox is always on the display, I want that this checkbox disappears from my display

Comment: Please leave feedback when you downvote so people trying to help can figure out how to improve their answers.

Comment: I can't, I'm new and I have to get points on this forum for leave a feedback

Comment: @Biondo, I don't think Patrick was talking to you. this looks like a good answer and the only reason I can see why it might get downvoted is because technically there's a syntax error missing a semicolon `;` at the end of this line `$html = "...`

Comment: There, [I added the semi-colon](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37902955/revisions). Looks good to me now.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide it with `style="display:none;"`
But since it is hidden, does it have to be a checkbox?
A regular hidden input would do the job, too.