# When can I access an id created in a <template if> tag in polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have this code:

```
    <template repeat="{{user in today}}">
        <template if="{{user.yesterday == null}}">
            <template if="{{user.id == userid}}">
                <div id="me">
                    <div class="username"><a href="mailto:{{user.email}}" class="nodecor">{{user.name}}</a></div>
                    <span class="absent">Didn't show up!</span><br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </template>
            <template if="{{user.id != userid}}">
                <div class="username"><a href="mailto:{{user.email}}" class="nodecor">{{user.name}}</a></div>
                <span class="absent">Didn't show up!</span><br />
                <br />
            </template>
        </template>
    </template>
```

The template-if's are all working.
But, when I try to access id 'me', it tells me it is either undefined or null.
Using:

this.$.me

only works if it's not inside a template-if.
I am accessing it from 'ready', like this:

```
    Polymer(
        'meeting-card',
        {
            ready:
                function() {
                    enter = this.$.enter;
                    dontenter = this.$.dontenter;
                    me = this.$.me;
                    checkHours();
                    checkInterval = setInterval(
                        function() {
                            checkHours();
                        },
                        15000
                    );
                }
        }
```

Both enter and dontenter work, but me does not.
The only difference is that enter and dontenter div's are not inside template-if tags.

Should I use a class name to access that div, instead?
If not, what is the right way to access that div, by Id?

Thanks.

Comment: `this.$` is a shorthand for accessing your element's shadow DOM, but `<div id="me'>` isn't part of your element's shadow DOM until `<template if="{{user.id == userid}}">` evaluates as true. It would help if you could provide a full example illustrating what you plan on doing to `<div id="me'>`, since there might be a cleaner way of doing what you want via expressions within the template.

Comment: Thanks.
I was able to access the id by using:

me = self.shadowRoot.querySelector('#me');

I just had to create a variable 'self', which I load with this on 'ready:', like such:

ready: function() { self = this; }

Then, I am able to access the id, using:

me = self.shadowRoot.querySelector('#me');

It makes sense, after all. (I am accessing it from an onInterval which is responsible for updating part of the element state).

Comment: I'm glad you have a better handle on things, but I still wonder whether there's a cleaner approach that just makes use of expressions within a template. If you'd like to pursue it further, could you pass along a full, working example?

Comment: Oh, yes, there was a cleaner approach to that. :)
What I was trying to do was to show/hide a div, based on the time (the card should be only visible until 10:15AM).
After reading your advice, I did it in a totally different way.
I did: <div class="{{cardVisibility}}"> - all I had to do, then, was: this.cardVisibility = 'showme' or this.cardVisibility = 'hideme'. Two-way data biding is awesome! Thanks again...

Comment: EDIT: Actually, I never paid attention to template expressions before; When I read it on your comment, I read about it, thanks!

Comment: Now, I have solved the problem I had, and have learned a cool new trick (template expressions). But, I would still like to know if there is an event or some other way to know when all conditional/repeat templates have been stamped. Is there an event, or any other way to check it? My guess is there isn't - I am not sure there would even be any use for that, but, still, is there any? :)

Comment: Here's something even cooler: there's a specific syntax for conditional attributes, which is a clean way of, e.g., applying the [hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708247/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hidden-attribute-html5-and-the-displaynone) attribute to an element. There's an example at http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-attributes

Comment: You can also use `this.async(function(){ /* do stuff */}.bind(this));` to wait until after conditional templates and repeats have had a chance to fire. Also beware with `self = this` (rather than e.g. `var self = this`, which you may have meant but kept things short for the comment). `self = this` would create a global with all the troubles that follow.

Comment: See https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/460