# How does css checkbox hack work?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I just came across the switch toggle button which is created only using css. It known as the checkbox hack.

For those who doesn't know what a checkbox css hack is, Please read it here

https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

I tried it out and it was working perfectly fine. But I didn't understand how this is working because we are not clicking on the checkbox.

So I have 2 questions

1. How is this working ?
2. Instead of absolute positioning I tried it with  `display: none;` 
   It still worked. Does this method have any drawbacks?

Comment: I've seen it where on iOS, the new checkbox image will not display the changed value. So when you click on it, the value changed to unchecked, but the user viewed a checked button that looked like nothing had occurred.

Comment: Have you never heard of the `<label>` tag?

Comment: The way I got around that was to literally hide and show any checkboxes you click. This made iOS rerender the checkboxes.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  l.. I have heard.. Could you please explain the connection between these two?

Comment: `<label>` lets you define a thing that can be clicked on to trigger the element referenced by `for`, or the checkbox inside it. A basic example would be `<label><input type="checkbox" /> You can click this text!</label>`.

Comment: The `<label>` tag is clearly mentioned in the article you linked to...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way it works is by using the `<label>` element. Any input element can (and usually should) have a label. You can tell the browser which label belongs to which label by using a `for` attribute, referring to the input's `name`:

```
<input name="myName" />
<label for="myName">Label</label>
```

Whenever you click the label, it focuses the input (or in case of checkboxes, toggles it).

The label and checkbox don't have to be near each other. You could add a few hidden checkboxes at the start or end of a document and place the labels anywhere on the page, and they'd still focus the input.

Hiding the checkbox through `display: none` could cause buggy behavior on certain browsers. Just hiding it from view by a `position: absolute` is safer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can bind `label`s to `checkboxes`/`radios` using the `for=` attribute. When this is set, clicking on the label toggles the checkbox. This is a [standard HTML attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp).
2. You can hide the checkbox using display: none, but do test it to make sure that its value is still submitted with the form.

Answer (score 1):

### *CSS is **aware*** of the current *checked* state of a checkbox *input*

This awareness, in combination of siblings selectors such as `+` *(immediate next sibling)* and `~` *(next sibling somewhere)* allows styling different styles, for checked/unchecked states, to *anything that comes after the input* element. The key here is the word "after".

### Basic example:

```css
/* styles when checkbox is unchecked */
div{ border:2px solid blue; margin:10px }
div h3{ color:red; }


/* when checkbox is checked */
input:checked ~ div{ background:blue; }
input:checked ~ div h3{ color:gold; }
```

```html
<input type=checkbox>

<div><h3>very<h3></div>
<div><h3>cool<h3></div>
```

As others have said (but is not a must) - HTML `label` element allows to interact with `input` elements, and in `checkbox/radio` types' case - it allows to toggle their `checked` state by clicking the label itself, which is "linked" to a specific `input` element by the `for` attribute:

```html
<label for='x`>click</label>
```

and the `id` attribute no the linked input:

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='x'>
```

For the method to work, the input element *must* to be placed *before* whatever element(s) it is intended to control via CSS.

In real-word use cases, one would often want to use the CSS-toggling features of a checkbox over next siblings, but to obscure the fact there is a checkbox involved. [The best way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6708247/104380) is by applying the [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute on the `input`, which only toggles off the rendering of the input, nothing else.

The example below showcase such use case for a simple *accordion* component:

### Practical example: Accordion

```css
.accordion{ width: 300px; border: 1px solid silver; }
.accordion label{ display:block; padding:1em; cursor:pointer; }
.accordion label:hover{ color:red; } 

.accordion > div:not(:last-child){ border-bottom:1px solid silver; }
.accordion .more{ max-height:0; transition:.5s; color:green; padding:0 1em; overflow: hidden; }

/* checked toggled */
.accordion input:checked + .content{ background:#EEE; }
.accordion input:checked + .content .more{ max-height:200px; }
```

```html
<div class='accordion'>
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_item_1' hidden>
    <div class='content'>
      <label for='checkbox_item_1'>Title 1</label>
      <div class='more'>
        <p>This is cool<p>
        <p>Yes it is</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox_item_2' hidden>
    <div class='content'>
      <label for='checkbox_item_2'>Title 2</label>
      <div class='more'>
        <p>This is also cool</p>
        <p>So much fun</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the checkbox with `visibility: hidden;` or `opacity: 0;` besides `display: none;` but i'm not sure which one is better.