# What's the difference between HTML 'hidden' and 'aria-hidden' attributes?

Tags: html, wai-aria

I have been seeing the aria attribute all over while working with Angular Material. Can someone explain to me, what the aria prefix means? but most importantly what I'm trying to understand is the difference between `aria-hidden` and `hidden` attribute.

Comment: I found some clarification here: http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/

Comment: Hidden removes from DOM tree, aria-hidden removes from accessibility tree

Answer (score 432, accepted):

ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications) defines a way to make Web content and Web applications more accessible to people with disabilities.

The `hidden` attribute is new in HTML5 and tells **browsers** not to display the element. The `aria-hidden` property tells **screen-readers** if they should ignore the element. Have a look at the w3 docs for more details:

https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden

Using these standards can make it easier for disabled people to use the web.

Comment: So if you just use hidden attribute, screen reader will still read?

Comment: Correct. `hidden` means hidden to everyone. `aria-hidden` means hidden to screen readers and similar tools. This is useful for components which are used purely for formatting and contain no real content, for instance.

Comment: `aria-hidden` Indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible or perceivable to any user or the reader

Comment: @AndreiBârsan @DanielKobe I think Andrei meant "Incorrect." (The rest of his comment is factual.) `hidden` should prevent the screen reader from accessing the tag's contents.

Comment: Your answer about `aria-hidden` is correct; however, you said nothing about `hidden` to differentiate it from `aria-hidden`. This is unfortunately the best answer. Please be more thorough on your answers.

Comment: your answer explains the *effects* of the attributes, but not their *meaning*. you mention nothing about the accessibility tree or the temporal relevance of an element. read the specs for more info. [[HTML 5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute), [ARIA 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-hidden)]

Comment: Point to remember is if its applied on parent , all child elements gets hidden

Comment: Thank you for this. Google linked me to wrong information (https://web.dev/learn/forms/security-privacy/). On this page, they are promoting the use of `aria-hidden="true"` and `hidden` on the input tag. This combination is not valid according to W3C, so I'm glad to learn that I don't need the aria-hidden attribute.

Comment: This is the perfect answer to the problem I was trying to solve, thanks!

Answer (score 54):

A hidden attribute is a boolean attribute (True/False). When this attribute is used on an element, it removes all relevance to that element. When a user views the html page, elements with the hidden attribute should not be visible.

Example:

```
    <p hidden>You can't see this</p>
```

Aria-hidden attributes indicate that the element and ALL of its descendants are still visible in the browser, but will be invisible to accessibility tools, such as screen readers.

Example:

```
    <p aria-hidden="true">You can't see this</p>
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/). It should answer all your questions.

**Note:** ARIA stands for Accessible Rich Internet Applications

**Sources:** [Paciello Group](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/)

Comment: This is not entirely correct (even the official documentation is a bit hazy here). An element with `aria-hidden="true"` is still visible in the browser, but will be invisible to accessibility tools, such as screen readers.

Comment: `aria-hidden` is used to hide the element from people using your website with accessibility tools.

Answer (score 22):

## Semantic Difference

According to [HTML 5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute):

> When specified on an element, [the `hidden` attribute] indicates that the element is not yet, or is no longer, directly relevant to the page’s current state, or that it is being used to declare content to be reused by other parts of the page as opposed to being directly accessed by the user.

Examples include a tab list where some panels are not exposed, or a log-in screen that goes away after a user logs in. I like to call these things “temporally relevant” i.e. they are relevant based on timing.

On the other hand, [ARIA 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-hidden) says:

> [The `aria-hidden` state] indicates whether an element is exposed to the accessibility API.

In other words, elements with `aria-hidden="true"` are removed from the [**accessibility tree**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-builtin/the-accessibility-tree), which most assistive technology honors, and elements with `aria-hidden="false"` will definitely be exposed to the tree. Elements without the `aria-hidden` attribute are in the "undefined (default)" state, which means user agents should expose it to the tree based on its rendering. E.g. a user agent may decide to remove it if its text color matches its background color.

Now let’s compare semantics. It’s appropriate to use `hidden`, but *not* `aria-hidden`, for an element that is not yet “temporally relevant”, but that might become relevant in the future (in which case you would use dynamic scripts to remove the `hidden` attribute). Conversely, it’s appropriate to use `aria-hidden`, but not `hidden`, on an element that is always relevant, but with which you don’t want to clutter the accessibility API; such elements might include “visual flair”, like icons and/or imagery that are not essential for the user to consume.

## Effective Difference

The **semantics** have predictable **effects** in browsers/user agents. The reason I make a distinction is that user agent behavior is *recommended*, but not *required* by the specifications.

The `hidden` attribute should hide an element from *all* presentations, including printers and screen readers (assuming these devices honor the HTML specs). If you want to remove an element from the accessibility tree *as well as* visual media, `hidden` would do the trick. However, do not use `hidden` *just because* you want this effect. Ask yourself if `hidden` is semantically correct first (see above). If `hidden` is not semantically correct, but you still want to visually hide the element, you can use other techniques such as CSS.

Elements with `aria-hidden="true"` are not exposed to the accessibility tree, so for example, screen readers won’t announce them. This technique should be used carefully, as it will provide different experiences to different users: accessible user agents won’t announce/render them, but they are still rendered on visual agents. This can be a good thing when done correctly, but it has the potential to be abused.

## Syntactic Difference

Lastly, there is a difference in syntax between the two attributes.

`hidden` is a **boolean attribute**, meaning if the attribute is present it is true—regardless of whatever value it might have—and if the attribute is absent it is false. For the true case, the best practice is to either use no value at all (`<div hidden>...</div>`), or the empty string value (`<div hidden="">...</div>`). I would *not* recommend `hidden="true"` because someone reading/updating your code might infer that `hidden="false"` would have the opposite effect, which is simply incorrect.

`aria-hidden`, by contrast, is an **enumerated attribute**, allowing one of a finite list of values. If the `aria-hidden` attribute is present, its value must be either `"true"` or `"false"`. If you want the "undefined (default)" state, remove the attribute altogether.

---

Further reading:
https://github.com/chharvey/chharvey.github.io/wiki/Hidden-Content

Comment: This post from Paciello Group, 2012 says: "aria-hidden=false is not mapped in any browser that supports aria-hidden, thus its use has no meaning or in other words has the same meaning as its absence."

Not sure if that's still the case, but adding as a caution. I'd love to describe my a11y view states separately from my CSS, but not sure it's possible with aria-hidden.

https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/

Comment: Recently the `hidden` attribute became an Enumerated attribute as well since it has a new value `until-found`.