# Radio Button SharePoint HTML Issue

Tags: html, sharepoint, radio-button

The HTML code I provided works in an online HTML editor, but as soon as I use it on my SharePoint site it deletes the Checked="Checked" that's pre-selecting the radio button. What is going on? Anything helps, thanks.

```
        <input class="carousel-open" type="radio" id="carousel-1" name="carousel" aria-hidden="true" checked="checked">
```

Comment: I don't see the checked="checked" in there

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```html
<input type="radio" name="r" id="id2" value="2" /> <label for="id2">not selected</label><br>

<input type="radio" name="r" id="id1" value="1" checked /> <label for="id1">already selected</label><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make my radio button automatically selected when the page
>   loads?

1) You haven't implemented the `checked` attribute.

2) Remove the `hidden` attribute that you currently have, otherwise, the radio buttons won't be visible.

```html
<input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio"  checked="checked" />

<input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio"   />
```

Relevant Reading:

[**What's the difference between HTML 'hidden' and 'aria-hidden' attributes?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107040/whats-the-difference-between-html-hidden-and-aria-hidden-attributes)

[**HTML checked Attribute**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki because you've got the hidden attribute on hence you cant see it

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki remove the hidden attribute

Comment: why not see the snippet i have provided? and if it doesn't work then update your question and i will look at your full markup.

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki can you please update your post with your full markup?, the solution i have provided obviously works because the snippet proves it and like i said please update your post with your full markup.

Comment: When I create this is on an online HTML editor, using Checked="Checked" works but when I use that code on my SharePoint page it removes the Checked="Checked" like its saying its not valid HTML code to use.

Comment: It works in the HTML editor, but again when I use that code on my SharePoint page it removes the Checked="Checked"