# When using a stroke and fill on a font to create layers, how do I hide the duplicate text from screen readers and search engine bots?

Tags: html, css, seo, wai-aria

I'm trying to build a h1 with a typography splitted in two fonts: stroke font and fill font:

[image]

Overlapping both layers I can take control of fill and stroke colors:

[image]

The problem is that, in the HTML markup, I need to duplicate contents. Something like this:

```
<h1>
    <span style="font-family:fill;">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span style="font-family:stroke;">Lorem Ipsum</span>
</h1>
```

I ask for some method for hide one of them in the DOM for robots and blind people devices. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Delete it and they won't see it.

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you are after using pseudo elements. Please can you supply a reproducible example (HTML, CSS and font).

Comment: user5014677: If I do that, I lose control of fill and stroke colors. I need to keep both for render fonts in the screen, but hide one of them for indexing robots.

Comment: Hidden Hobbes: Yes! of course. Good idea! I will try it.

Comment: Hidden Hobbes: I am thinking in this method. The H1 content is supplied dinamically by a WordPress CMS template. I can provide dinamically an inline style for the element, but I can't select `:before`or `:after` pseudo elements ouside de stylesheet. And I dont know how provide its contents dinamically in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aria-hidden` would seem to be what you require.

> In supporting browsers in conjunction with supporting assistive technology the content is not conveyed to the user via the assistive technology.

So this should work.

```
<h1>
    <span style="font-family:fill;">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    <span style="font-family:stroke;" aria-hidden="true">Lorem Ipsum</span>
</h1>
```

See also [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107040/whats-the-difference-between-html-hidden-and-aria-hidden-attributes)

Comment: That is what I need. Thank you very much!