# aria-hidden property not working on descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, wai-aria, web-frontend

Chrome Accessibility Tools complains that certain children of an overlay box do not have the right contrast ratio. It seems like the tool considers the children to be "visible" when the overlay is hidden.

I can see the `aria-hidden` property of the overlay being correctly set in the inspector as I open/close it, though (using `attr("aria-hidden","false");`).

Setting `aria-hidden="true";` through the inspector on the children individually fixes this problem.

I am confused as aria-hidden is supposed to hide the element *and* its children. 
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between HTML 'hidden' and 'aria-hidden' attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107040/whats-the-difference-between-html-hidden-and-aria-hidden-attributes)

Comment: `hidden` means hidden to everyone. `aria-hidden` means hidden to screen readers and similar tools

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your comments, it made me realise I was indeed confused by what the audit tool was checking.

I used the advice given [on the w3 website](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) regarding putting `[aria-hidden="true"] { visibility: hidden; }` in my code, which properly hides the overlay when its aria-hidden property is set to true, and results in the audit tool being happy. :)

Comment: Thanks, this answer perfectly solves the problem I was running into!