# Bootstrap dismissible alert keeps showing on the page load

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf, alert

```
 <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible " aria-hidden="true">
       <button type="button" class="close " aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
       <strong th:text="${error}"></strong>
 </div>
```

Though I have used aria-hidden="true" the alert keeps showing on the page load as it is shown in the image. Any quick advice please?

[image]

Comment: And what exactly is it you think `aria-hidden` does?

Comment: Perhaps try adding `th:if="${error}"` to your `<div>`

Comment: th:if="${error}" this worked. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31107263/283366)

> The `aria-hidden` property tells **screen-readers** if they should ignore the element

What you want is to hide the element if there is no error. For this, use

```
th:if="${error}"
```

on your `<div>` element.