# Is presence of aria-hidden sufficient or is value set to "true" required (aria-hidden="true")

Tags: html, hidden, wai-aria

The html "hidden" attribute is a  boolean and does NOT need a value set.  It's mere presence is sufficient.

What about the "aria-hidden" attribute?  Is it's mere presence sufficient?  Or does it require the value "true" to be set?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-hidden its recommended to use a value.

Comment: The answer is `aria-hidden="true|false"` as this field is meant to be handled by *screen reader*. You can find more details here https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/

Comment: Read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107040/whats-the-difference-between-html-hidden-and-aria-hidden-attributes). It has links to some info as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aria-hidden` must have a value of true|false.  Note, however, that `aria-hidden` is **not** needed if you are using the `hidden` attribute or if you are using CSS `visibility:none` or `display:hidden`.  All three of these latter three ways to hide will also hide the element from a screen reader.  You only need `aria-hidden="true"` if there's something on the display that you want to hide from a screen reader, such as a decorative element that does not add meaning to the page.

If you are "hiding" an object by setting its font size to 0 or using a clipping rectangle or "pushing" the element off the screen with `x` or `y`, then you **will** need to set `aria-hidden="true"` on that element because the former techniques are only visually hiding the element and not truly hiding the element.

Answer (score 1):

You must supply a value for aria-hidden.

"If an element is only visible after some user action, authors MUST set the aria-hidden attribute to true. When the element is presented, authors MUST set the aria-hidden attribute to false or remove the attribute, indicating that the element is visible."

https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden