# Unable to find dropdown in selenium which is hidden

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

I am trying to inspect dropdown in selenium using java which is displayed on the frontend but it is having 'aria-hidden='true' in its source code.. but it is giving me error as 'Element not interactable'.
Have tried using below options:

1. 'WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated'
2. Select class
3. Xpath, id & classname

Code snip:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); //First click on dropdown to show options 

WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select[id='lender_id']"))); 

dropdown.click(); //Now find desired option and click

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select[id='lender_id']"))).click();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking it first? please shear your code.

Comment: Can you provide the URL for this?

Comment: @MosheSlavin please find below code for this:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//First click on dropdown to show options 
WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select[id='lender_id']")));
dropdown.click();

//Now find desired option and click 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select[id='lender_id']"))).click();

Comment: @YaDavMaNish sorry i cant provide the url for this

Comment: @YaDavMaNish i tried using xpath but got the same error

Comment: @Pooja can you add to the question the relevant HTML. including the select and options

Comment: @MosheSlavin done please check

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Select class.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select[id='lender_id']"))); 

new Select(element).selectByValue(valueToSelect);
```

Comment: tried this but still getting error 'element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated'

Answer (score 0):

`aria-hidden=true` attributes indicate that the element and All of its
descendants are still visible in the browser, but will be invisible to
accessibility tools, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107040/whats-the-difference-between-html-hidden-and-aria-hidden-attributes)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);  

WebElement dropdown = 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-group']//select[starts-with(@id,'lender_id') and starts-with(@name,'lender_id')]")); 

Select select = new Select(dropdown);
select.selectByValue("value");
```

Comment: tried this but still getting error 'element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated'

Comment: @Pooja can you pls share the html source for this