# Angular2: conditional display, bind to [hidden] property vs. *ngIf directive

Tags: html, angular

In Angular2, let's say I want to conditionally display a `<div>` block. What's the difference between the following two ways.

1. `<div [hidden]=isLoaded>Hello World!</div>` where `isLoaded` is a boolean in corresponding `.ts` file.
2. `<div *ngIf=isLoaded>Hello World!</div>`

I do know that even if the `<div>` is not shown in the page, 1. still has the `<div>` in the DOM while 2. doesn't. Are there any other differences? What're the pros and cons of each of them?

Comment: Given that you already know the difference, what do you actually want to know?

Comment: that's the difference.. let's consider the case,you have a dropdown of 100 cities.
=> your list be displayed as soon as you click on the dropdown as it is already on the DOM, while in other case list of cities will be created on DOM & then it would be displayed, so in this case it will appear after a certain delay. Depends on you how you want to use it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i'm not sure if there are other differences and want to learn which way is preferred. By the way, I also don't know what's [class.hidden], why did you remove it from the question?

Comment: Which is preferred is a meaningless question; should you use a hammer or a screwdriver?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular2/35578093#35578093

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your linked answer is exactly what I'm looking for, Thank you~

Answer (score 55):

The difference is that `*ngIf` will remove the element from the DOM, while `[hidden]` actually plays with the CSS style by setting `display:none`. However, the problem with `[hidden]` is that it can be overiden so the `div`, as in your case, would be displayed and you would be scratching your head why it doesn't work.

To sum things up, `*ngIf` and `[hidden]` are **not** the same at all. The former removes an element from DOM, while the latter toggles `display` CSS property.

Comment: @BingLu It binds to [hidden attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708247/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hidden-attribute-html5-and-the-displaynone).

Comment: It's not class hidden. It is an attribute that manipulates the CSS display property.

Comment: If you add `[hidden] { display: none !important;}` to your CSS setting `[hidden]` should work fine. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578083/what-is-the-equivalent-of-ngshow-and-nghide-in-angular2/35578093#35578093

Comment: Can one say that `[hidden]` is faster than `*ngIf`?

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek to my understanding, rather the opposite. [hidden] keeps the object(s) in DOM and thus takes up memory and also other resources as Angular will keep tracking changes to these objects even if they are hidden. Thus, especially with large object trees, it would be beneficial to use *ngIf. However, adding to/removing from the DOM also carries a computational cost. One should probably test both options with, e.g., jsPerf if perfomance is paramount.

Comment: It is not **ngIf will remove* it is not rendered, I know this is almost the same thing but its easier to understand when you get the methodology right.

Comment: this is a useful trick when using labels with the `[for]` attribute; `*ngIf` will give an error on the input you are trying to hide, but `[hidden]` will not