# View Not Updating Immediately From Service with element.classList.add()

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am adding a `css` class to elements from a service, but the changes do not happen immediately. The changes take about a second to update the view. I need the changes to happen immediately with no delay. I have tried an ApplicaionRef and calling `this.applicationRef.tick()` in the service, but that did not work. I tried running the service's method in NgZone's `this.zone.run`, but that also did not work.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'calling',
  templateUrl: './calling.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calling.component.scss']
})
export class CallingComponent {
 constructor(private hidingService: HidingService) {}

 callHide() {
  this.hidingService.hide();
 }
}
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HidingService {
 constructor() {}

 hide() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.hideable-field');
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.classList.add('hide');
  });
 }
}
```

Here's the CSS that's in styles.css (accessible from all components) for reference, but this part is working. Adding this 'hide' class hides the field with this CSS:

```
.hideable-field {
  &.hide {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }
}
```

If I use this hiding logic in the Component, it works. The fields are hidden immediately. If I use this hidden logic in the service it takes a moment.

Comment: Not sure about the lag in service vs component. but you might want to update your logic and use renderer2 `this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, className);`  to make it more angular.
Also for operations like this, i'd prefer to use directives on elements rather than using querySelectorAll to find the elements. its cleaner and more angular way.

Comment: May be there are many elements with `.hideable-field` class and iterating all the elements in forEach may be the reason for this delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be waiting for the UI to be updated before returning. There is a method called requestAnimationFrame() that allows you to do this.

```
export class HidingService {
 constructor() {}

 hide(): Observable<{}> {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.hideable-field');
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.classList.add('hide');
  });

  const subject = new Subject();
  requestAnimationFrame( () => {
    // Fields will hide in this frame
    requestAnimationFrame( () => {
      // Fields are hidden
      subject.next(); 
    });
  });
  return subject.pipe();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's typically an anti-pattern to have a service make changes that directly affect the HTML of your component.  It's also not a good idea to use document query selectors in Angular.  BUT, if you want to get something working quickly, try wrapping a timeout around the `hide` function in your service:

```
 hide() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.hideable-field');
    elements.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.add('hide');
    });
  }, 0)
 }
```

A more correct approach would be to have a boolean `isHidden` property on each of your objects.  Then, from within your template you can use `[hidden]` or `*ngIf` to conditionally display them.  See [Angular2: conditional display, bind to [hidden] property vs. *ngIf directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777990/angular2-conditional-display-bind-to-hidden-property-vs-ngif-directive) for a description of the difference between the two approaches. An example using `*ngIf`:

Somewhere in your component's template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let element of myElements'>
  <div class='my-element' *ngIf='!element.isHidden'></div>
</ng-container>
```

The new hide function in your **component**:

```
 hide() {
   this.myElements.forEach(element => element.isHidden = true);
 }
```