# how to pass attribute in argument to a function

Tags: javascript

i want to create function to apply any attribute or function to all selectors
what is the correct way to do it

```
function applyToAll(elm,func)
  {
   let i = elm.length; while (i--) { elm[i].func; }
  }

  li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  hide = style.display = "none";

  applyToAll(li,hide) // Uncaught ReferenceError: style is not defined
```

i can pass the property direct like this

```
let i = elm.length; while (i--) { elm[i].style.display = "none"; }
```

but i want let function dynamic so i can use for example :

```
prop = innerHTML = "<b>something</b>";
let i = elm.length; while (i--) { elm[i].prop }
```

Comment: I think you want: `hide = e => e.style.display = "none";`

Comment: `elem[i].prop` doesn't do anything Do you want to set it to a certain value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes:

```
function applyToAll(elm, func) {
    let i = elm.length;
    while (i--) {
        func(elm[i])  // <---
    }
}

li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
hide = e => e.style.display = "none";  // <---


applyToAll(li, hide)
```

Change 1: `func` is not a method, and cannot be called with a dot

Change 2: just `style.display = ...` is an expression which is evaluated immediately, on the other side, `e => e.style.display` is a function which is evaluated on call.

As a side note, [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a `NodeList` which already provides [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) which is exactly what your function does, up to the order of the application.

Comment: @connexo there *is* a difference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708247/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hidden-attribute-html5-and-the-displaynone), but I don't know if it is enough to prevent the switch of use to the `hidden` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

From what the comments say and what I see, I think your `hide` variable is meant to contain an arrow function.

It should be re-written to this (as shown in the comments).

```
hide = e => e.style.display = "none";
```

Also, the `func` parameter as an argument isn't bound to the passed in element, it is bound to a variable as one of the function's arguments (in this case, it contains the function of `hide`.

In addition, you also have to call functions with `()`.
Otherwise, it means pretty much nothing in your context;

So, in your while loop, change this:

```
elem[i].func;
```

to this:

```
func(elem[i]);
```

This executes your function as a callback and passes in the element as an argument.

One more thing:  since I don't see hide declared anywhere else (or redeclared for that matter), if the latter is true then I recommend using a `const` variable declaration keyword.

So, your hide function declaration statement should be changed to this:

```
const hide = e => e.style.display = "none";
```

This tells the interpreter that you are declaring a variable.

While technically (in non-strict mode), omitting the variable declaration keyword *is* oftentimes accepted, it's bad practice.

For more info, see: [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when should I use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-should-i-use-it-or-omit-it)

You also seem to be having trouble with arrow functions.

I recommend reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to eliminate any confusion with how arrow functions are used/formed.