# Javascript Multiple validation error message failed

Tags: javascript, validation

I am unable to figure where is the issue in my JavaScript code. I want show and hide the error message based on whether the field value is empty or not.

```
if (info == "" && hrContacts == "") {
    document.getElementById("hr_contacts_error").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("info_error").style.display = "block";
    return false;
} else if (hrContacts == "") {       
    document.getElementById("hr_contacts_error").style.display = "block";
    return false;
} else if (hrContacts != "") {
    document.getElementById("hr_contacts_error").style.display = "none";
} else if (info == "") {
    document.getElementById("info_error").style.display = "block";
    return false;
} else if (info != "") {
    document.getElementById("info_error").style.display = "none";
} else if (info != "" && hrContacts != "") {
    form submit
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this a lot.

1. First, set the initial state, assume there are no errors, and hide all messages.
2. Check every individual field, and if there's an input error, display the message, and set the error tracking boolean to `true`.
3. If at the end, there are any errors, `return false` to prevent form submit.
4. Actually submit the form, if there's no errors.

```
let hasError = false;
document.getElementById("hr_contacts_error").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("info_error").style.display = "none";

if (hrContacts == "") {
  document.getElementById("hr_contacts_error").style.display = "block";
  hasError = true;
}
if (info == "") {
  document.getElementById("info_error").style.display = "block";
  hasError = true;
}

if (hasError) {
  return false;
}

// form submit
```

You could reduce some code duplication like this:

```
let hasError = false;

// Loop over all fields with their error message ID.
[
    [hrContacts, 'hr_contacts_error'],
    [info, 'info_error']
].forEach(([value, errorId]) => {
    const isEmpty = value == '';
    document.getElementById(errorId).style.display = isEmpty ? 'block' : 'none';
    hasError = hasError || isEmpty;
});

if (hasError) {
    return false;
}

// form submit
```

Comment: Np.

I just added a even neater version, @jvk. If you have more fiels, it just takes an extra row in that arrauy.

Comment: So how will the screen reader handle that you do not change the aria-hidden attribute?

Comment: Screen readers generally ignore anything with `display: none` @mplungjan.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do :

```
document.getElementById("hr_contacts_error").style.display = hrContacts == "" ? "block" : "none";
document.getElementById("info_error").style.display = info == "" ? "block" : "none";

if(hrContacts != "" && info != "") {
    /* form submit */
} else {
    // if you need to
    return false;
}
```

no need for all those if/else

Also try to rely on native html validation as much as you can, like maxlength, min, max attributes and so on

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell us how you call the validation.

Here is how you SHOULD call it

NOTE: Simply adding `required` to the form fields can replace the validation of empty fields completely

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // page load
  document.getElementById("formID").addEventListner("submit", (e) => { // form submission - do not call anything "submit" in your form
    const hrContactsValue = document.getElementById("hr_contacts").value.trim();
    const infoValue = document.getElementById("info").value.trim();
    document.getElementById("hr_contacts_error").hidden = hrContactsValue !== "";
    document.getElementById("info_error").hidden = infoValue !== "";
    if (hrContactsValue === "" || infoValue === "") {
      e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    }
    // here form will submit
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd not use the `hidden` attribute... https://stackoverflow.com/a/64644217/1835379 . You're also checking the same condition twice, but opposite for each field. That seems error-prone.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks for the correction but what do you mean opposite? Ah, the === instead of the already fixed !==

Comment: @Cerbrus If I read that, I would PREFER hidden than to style.display, since that does NOT set the ARIA-HIDDEN at all. A good screen reader should handle hidden better than changes to a class or style

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, It is a basic javascript validation