# Is there an equivalent of Vue's `v-show` in Angular so that the component is hidden, but still in DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, vue.js

There are some situations where it's better to keep a hidden component in DOM. In Vue there the `v-show` in addition to the `v-if`. But in Angular I didn't find an equivalent? So the best solution is to use s.th. like `[ngStyle]="{ 'display': showMe ? 'block' : 'none' }"`?

EDIT: I also could set the [`hidden` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708247/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hidden-attribute-html5-and-the-displaynone), which should have a very similar effect, e.g. `[hidden]="!showMe"`.

Is there actually a reason why Vue.js did include `v-show` instead of simply using `:hidden`?

Comment: Your example is indeed correct. `v-show` is also just toggling `display` under the hood. Or you can also use the HTML attribute `hidden`, e.g. `[hidden]="!showMe"`

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right. I edited the question to give it a slightly different directly :-)

Comment: The second question might be opinion based, I don't expect there to be any official statements on why Vue has made their framework design choices. Maybe the reason is that `hidden` works with CSS and can be overridden by simply specifying the `display` CSS property on the element, like pointed out in the linked answer. This is why I needed to add the following global styles in my applications: `[hidden] { display: none !important }`. So `v-show` and `:hidden` may not lead to the same result.

Comment: Frameworks are all about convenience. You can technically do everything with vanilla javascript. Frameworks exist to help you write less. If there is some code developers found they write so frequently, they make a shorthand for it.

Comment: You can also use:`[style.display]="!showMe?'none':null"`

Comment: Ironically, Vue borrowed it from Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-show` is simply sugar syntax for adding `style="display: none"`. While I'm not aware of anything like that built into angular, it's trivial to build your own directive that will achieve the same result (code not tested):

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'appHidden',
})
class HiddenDirective {
 @Input('appHidden')
 isHidden: boolean = false;

 @HostBinding('style.display')
 get displayStyle() {
   return this.isHidden ? 'none' : undefined;
 }
}
```

Usage:

```html
<div [appHidden]="shouldBeHidden"></div>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it overrides element's own display style, in case it's specified

Comment: @Estus Flask when `isHidden` is false, the `undefined` for host binding will cause angular to remove `display` from the element styles, thus restoring whatever the CSS-specified value is